# How to stop Cyberpanel from auto-creating "mail" subdomain

Tags: wordpress, cyber-panel

I just started using Cyberpanel, and this really disturbs me.

Cyberpanel will auto-create mail sub-domains for all my domains, and even after you delete everything, it will be recreated in a few days. (hosting WP sites)

Can someone please let me know how to stop it? Thanks.

Expected result: All the domains on Cyberpanel will not automatically create mail subdomains.